# linux hostname -f command is not working on RHEL

Tags: hostname

I am running a RHEL 5.7 and the `hostname` command gives me the correct hostname.
But `hostname -s` and `hostname -f` return: `Unknown host`. Why?

Comment: What distro? On my Ubuntu 12.04 system all 3 work.

Comment: What operating system are you using? If Linux, which distribution? What are the contents of `/etc/hostname`?

Comment: `hostname -f` uses DNS, do you have a reverse DNS entry for your IP?

Comment: @terdon I'm using RHEL5 (red hat enterprise linux server release 5.7 (tikanga)) and there is no such file (/etc/hostname)

Comment: @Barmar I don't have the dns configured on my host. I added the ip address and fqdn in my hosts file (/etc/hosts), this error is a result of dns not being configured ?

Comment: The man page says it will check `/etc/hosts`, assuming you have `/etc/host.conf` configured correctly.

Comment: +1 for @Barmar. Yes hostname -f uses reverse dns lookup to find the hostname with domainname. In my case hostname in /etc/hosts file was incorrect because of which reverse lookup was failing. After i corrected that i get the expected name.

Comment: your host name entry in /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network are not same

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*(copied from [one of my answers on SF](https://serverfault.com/a/367496/68920))*

The `hostname` command returns results from DNS and `/etc/hosts`.

`hostname` is equivilant to `uname -n` and is the actual "hostname" or "nodename" of the box.
All the other `hostname` arguments use this nodename to look up info.

So before going any further, I should explain the `/etc/hosts` file format.
The first field is fairly obvious, its the IP address all the hostnames on the line should resolve to. The second field is the primary hostname for that IP. The remaining fields are aliases.

So if you run `hostname -f` it will first try to resolve the IP for your nodename. Depending on how you have the `hosts:` entry configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` this method will vary.

- If you have it configured to use dns, it will use the search domains configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` until it gets an IP back from DNS.
- If you have it configured to use files it will look in `/etc/hosts` to find a line where either the primary hostname or the alias name is your current nodename (`uname -n`), and then return the IP address in that line.

Once it has the IP it will then try a reverse lookup on that IP. Again it will use DNS for this and your hosts file based on your `nsswitch.conf`. In the case of using your hosts file, it will return the primary entry (which is the first field after the IP in the file).

`hostname -a` will only work with the hosts file since doing a reverse lookup in DNS only gives you 1 result. With the hosts file it return the alises in the matching line (which is everything after the first entry, the primary hostname).

So in short, the likely reason for your issue is that you have no entry in `/etc/hosts` that contains your hostname (`uname -n`).

---

**Examples**
If your nodename is 'foobar', and you have an entry in `/etc/hosts` such as this:

```
127.0.0.1 foobar.example.com foobar localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Then you will get the following command results:

```
# hostname
foobar
# uname -n
foobar

# hostname -f
foobar.example.com

# hostname -a
foobar localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Comment: That explanation of how it gets the value is great! I had my FQDN at the end of the 127.0.0.1 line which had as primary hostname localhost. I just deleted them and left the FQDN only on the line that has the real IP, and it fixed my problem of hostname -f returning localhost.